# CSS styling not displaying in Browser

Tags: html, css, dreamweaver

I am designing a custom table for a website. In dreamweaver, `Design` tab shows exactly what I want but in `Live` tab no border and stuff is visible. I have tried to find solution, I might have overlooked something but I couldn't find solution yet. I am posting code here:

**CSS**

```
#tableData{
    font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size:16px;
    color:#09F; 

    padding-bottom:25px;
    padding-top:10px;

    border-bottom:thin;
    border-bottom-color:#09F;


}        


table{
    width:600px;
    border: 1px solid #666;
}


li{
    list-style:none;
    height:22px;
    border-bottom:1px;
    border-bottom-color:#09F;
}


#tableHeading{
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size:32px;
    color:#666; 
    padding:10px;
    float:left;
    padding-right:500px;
    border-left:thick;
    border-right:thick;
    border-left-color:#09F;
    border-right-color:#09F;

}
```

**HTML**

```
   <tr>
    <td id="tableData">
         <ul>
             <li>Android</li>
             <li>abced </li>
             <li>xyz</li>
         </ul>
   </td>
  </tr>
```

In Design View:

[image]

In Live View (Browser):

[image]

What am I doing wrong? How can I solve it?

Regards

Comment: Can you paste the HTML code which relates to the Table Heading, "Bio".

Comment: You've posted the Table Row contents, but not the header. The HTML you've submitted contains the three item list.

Comment: When specifying a border, you have to indicate the style.. your li would be `border:1px solid #09F` try that.

Comment: @JoshC but that border surrounds the whole row. Which is not required as shown above

Comment: Specify something then.. bottom, top, right, left..: `border-bottom:1px solid #09F`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the CSS for :-

```
#tableData{
    font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size:16px;
    color:#09F; 

    padding-bottom:25px;
    padding-top:10px;

    border-bottom-style:solid;/*Updated*/
    border-bottom-color:#09F;/*Updated*/

}

#tableHeading{
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size:32px;
    color:#666; 
    padding:10px;
    /*float:left;*/
    padding-right:500px;
    border-left: 5px solid #09F;
    border-right: 5px solid #09F;
}
```

You need to mention complete "**border-bottom-style**" and "**border-bottom-color**"

or use this instead "`border-bottom:1px solid #09F;`"

Please refer this Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aasthatuteja/gDkn6/

Hope this should help!

Answer (score 1):

replace

```
border-left:thick;
border-right:thick;
border-left-color:#09F;
border-right-color:#09F;
```

by

```
border-left:thick solid #09F;
border-right:thick solid #09F;
```

Answer (score 0):

The dotted border you see in Dreamweaver design view is generated to show you there is an element there, this is indeed not part of your page.

A border in CSS is made up of 3 main components: width, color and *style*.
The style property is the one you miss.

Change the border styles to:

```
border-bottom-width: thin;
border-bottom-color: #09F;
border-bottom-style: solid;
```

You can also use the shorthand for border bottom:

```
border-bottom: solid thin #09F;
```

Furthermore I'd advise you to use numerical values for width, like: `1px` so you know exactly what you get.